# What have i gotten wrong for this stored procedure not to execute?

Tags: sql

Here is the stored procedure and how I created it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STORED PROCEDURE SimpleSelect()
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Permissions
END;
/

CALL SimpleSelect();
```

When creating the procedure I get the error

> "Success with some compilation errors"

and when running the CALL command I get that the SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: Hi @badcoder11, you have asked for help, you have received help. It would be now nice from you to give your feedback to it. Is the answer of any help ? No ? Then comment why. Yes ? Then give it a vote up (when you will have 15 points you will be able to do this). Is it correct ? Yes ? Accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to know which database do you use. Some of this advice's will come in handy in many databases but some will not...

1. Do you have a table called **Permissions** already created ? If not, create it.
2. Please put a **`;`** after the `SELECT` statement. Like this:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM Permissions;
   ```

In MySQL this will not return error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SimpleSelect()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Permissions;
END;
/
```

When you fix your procedure the call command will work just fine...
Cheers!

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2ee36d10d9a007278294da49a176923b)

Comment: Hi @badcoder11, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please if this answer was correct to you you can accept it as correct. If it is not please do ask for additional help. Cheers!